# Plesk Tomcat 7 Axis Soap Monitor

Tags: java, tomcat7, apache-axis, plesk

When enabling the AXIS 2 Soap Monitor (described in [Link](https://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/docs/soapmonitor-module.html)) I receive the follwing exception via the JAVA console. The servlet is working fine, but it cannot communicate with the server. Do I have to add a specific policy to the Tomcat catalina policies?

```
java.security.AccessControlException: access denied ("java.net.SocketPermission" "IP:PORT" "connect,resolve")
at java.security.AccessControlContext.checkPermission(AccessControlContext.java:472)
at java.security.AccessController.checkPermission(AccessController.java:884)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkPermission(SecurityManager.java:549)
at java.lang.SecurityManager.checkConnect(SecurityManager.java:1051)
at sun.plugin2.applet.SecurityManagerHelper.checkConnectHelper(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.AWTAppletSecurityManager.checkConnect(Unknown Source)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:584)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:434)
at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:211)
at org.apache.axis2.soapmonitor.applet.SOAPMonitorApplet$SOAPMonitorPage.start(SOAPMonitorApplet.java:367)
at org.apache.axis2.soapmonitor.applet.SOAPMonitorApplet.start(SOAPMonitorApplet.java:110)
at com.sun.deploy.uitoolkit.impl.awt.AWTAppletAdapter.start(Unknown Source)
at sun.plugin2.applet.Plugin2Manager$AppletExecutionRunnable.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```